# Stop windows from closing sessions that access clipboard at same time

Tags: clipboard, session, exceptions, nomachine

I am using a program called "NoMachine". Its a remote access program. It works great except for one problem.

See, I use the program to connect to a remote host that has two monitors. I connect to the host twice so I have two remote sessions on my PC (think of it like two seperate RDP sessions). that way I can set the first session to monitor1 and the second to monitor2.

The problem is if I copy and paste into one session then paste into the other, one of the windows will abruptly close.

I reached out to support from NoMachine and they said *"The problem is due to a Windows exception raised due to the access to the clipboard by two different session processes."*

They don't have a way of fixing it at this time.

So my question is, is there a way I can stop windows from closing sessions just because they both access the clipboard? I tried disabling UAC, did not help. Not sure what else I can try.

Comment: Usually with RDP like programs, you can disable clipboard transfer. If you disable clipboard transfer to one of the monitors, it should  still work. Even though remote clipboard transfer will send it to monitor 1, the windows behind it will receive it on both monitors, and as such, on monitor 2 it also syncs.

Comment: How do you do this? I want to try it out. Not sure its possible in NoMachine, looks like its all clipboard or nothing. https://kb.nomachine.com/AR04L00798#:~:text=Disabling%20clipboard%20(copy%20and%20paste,the%20computer%20you%20are%20accessing.

Comment: No idea. I am not a user of NoMachine. You could contact support and ask how to disable clipboard sharing for one session, and not the other. Also, their software does seem to support having 1 connection with the ability to switch to a different monitor. Maybe that works better?